# Ansible hangs on the first run

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

Whenever I add a new machine and run the playbook for the first time it hangs. When I ssh to that machine from Ansible server and exit and run the playbook again then it works.

Comment: Please ask one question per question. I edited out the one that did not match the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely Ansible gets stuck on verifying a host key and when you connect with `ssh`, you are prompted and confirm it manually.

Add `host_key_checking=false` to your [Ansible configuration file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#host-key-checking).